# Buttons not fully loading in GridLayout

Tags: java

Im trying to make a 17 by 17 GridLayout board, but when i run the code the board that i generated is messed up and looks like this instead of a 17 by 17 button board:

[image]

So my question is why is the board displaying weird like this, and how do i get it to display the 17 by 17 button board that i want?

here is the code i am using:

```
public class TheJFrame {
public static final char[][] board = new char[17][17];
public static class TheJFramez {
    JFrame boardz = new JFrame("Game of Life");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public TheJFramez(){
        int r = 0,c;
        boardz.setLayout(new GridLayout(board.length,board[r].length,1,1));
        for(r=0;r<board.length;r++){
            for(c = 0;c<board[r].length;c++){
                JButton tats = new JButton(" " + board[r][c] + " ");
                panel.add(tats);

            }
        }
        boardz.add(panel);
        boardz.setVisible(true);
        boardz.setSize(1200, 700);
        boardz.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TheJFramez();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, You have set the Layout of 'boardz' to GridLayout while you are adding the buttons to 'panel' who's layout is not specified so, it is taking default layout , when you add the panel to 'boardz', the panel will be arranged in grid layout, While the components of 'panel' would still be in the default layout.

So, you want to add the JButton to boardz and there is no use of panel.

Here is the correct code :-

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TheJFrame {
public static final char[][] board = new char[17][17];
public static class TheJFramez {
    JFrame boardz = new JFrame("Game of Life");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public TheJFramez(){
        int r = 0,c;
        boardz.setLayout(new GridLayout(board.length,board[r].length));
        for(r=0;r<17;r++){
            for(c = 0;c<17;c++){
                JButton tats = new JButton(" " + board[r][c] + " ");
                boardz.add(tats);
                System.out.print(board[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        boardz.setVisible(true);
        boardz.setSize(1200, 700);
        boardz.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TheJFramez();
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

shubham you are right but the frame take default layout which is flowlayout. So they are arrange in linear way.so u can just set layout as gridlayout.